# find user is logged in or not uisng shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have small shell script which is used to test the condition whether used is logged in or not using if condition.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [  $# -ne 1 ]
then
        echo "Argument required"
        echo "Usage: on user"
else
        user="$1"

        if  who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null
        then
                echo "$user is logged in"
        else
                echo "$user is not logged in"
        fi
fi
```

This would be working correctly.

Now here is my question: if i try this if condition like below method means shell terminal through the error.

```
 if [ who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null ]

> Error ./user.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
  grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

could you please some tell what is the difference between these two test condition?

Comment: Why do you have the braces? `[`. `]` when trying in the terminal unlike in the script you had? Wouldn't that make it obvious for you to conclude that could be the problem

Answer (score 2):

In simple words, the `[` or `test` tests the results of **expression**, not *command list*.

Here is the syntax of `test` and `if`:

> test expr
>   [ expr ]
>
> if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi

Then in `if` construct, it can be followed by a *commmand list*.

So in `if  who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null`, it executes the command `who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null`, then test the *return status* of the command.

But in `if [ who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null ]`, it first executes the command `[ who | grep ^"$user " > /dev/null ]`, but **because of the `|`(pipeline)**, the commmand will be *parsed as two parts*:
1st: `[ who`, which will complain: "line 10: [: missing `]'"
2nd: `grep ^"$user " > /dev/null ]` which will complain: "grep: ]: No such file or directory".

As for the format of the **expression** of the `[` or `test`:
refer to [The classic test command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest). And the main four expressoins are:
**file tests**, **string tests**, **arithmetic tests**, **misc tests**.

Answer (score 0):

Use a function.

```
#!/bin/bash

logged_in () { who | grep ^"$1 " > /dev/null; }

if [  $# -ne 1 ]
then
    echo "Argument required"
    echo "Usage: on user"
else
    user="$1"

    if logged_in "$user"
    then
        echo "$user is logged in"
    else
        echo "$user is not logged in"
    fi
fi
```